# conformal map from disc to funny domain

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I am working on numerical experiment about the Riemann mapping theorem.
In order to test my program, I would like to have some test function on highly non-symmetric and non convex shape, funnier than this one :

[image]

Ideally, something like the standard test domain, like the rabbit:

[image]

But I need an exact conformal map like a rational function:
$$\left(\sum_{0}^n a_k z^k\right)/\left(\sum_{0}^m b_k z^k\right), $$
or at least something I can give to python.

Of course for the rabbit like domain, I am not expected to easily get something  perfectly resembling with a rational function, but at least something that is roughly comparable.

Does anyone knows where I can find this can kind of conformal parametrization? I have google many key words without any good result.
Thank in advance!

Edit:
Thanks to Matt E., I get the desired shape, an I am also able to interpolate, but the code for the interpolation using Bezier curves, so the coefficients correspond to splines functions. How can get some trigonometric ones with python? Then I have to hope that the harmonic extension is bijective in the interior of the disc.

[image]

Comment: Could you not *start* with a somewhat random truncated Laurent series, and determine a suitable conformally mapped domain form that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with some random coefficients and I have tried to move them, but it is hard (impossible) to get something like rabbit, mickey mousse head or any funny shape.

Comment: I think Laurent series with $w = r e^{i \theta}$ is related to Fourier series when $r = 1$, so maybe you could use Discrete Fourier Transform on a ordered loop of boundary points in $\mathbb{C}$ to get the coefficients?  I've seen on youtube it used to draw Homer Simpson's outline with epicycles, but that was self-intersecting, so I'm not sure if it'll work in all cases...

Comment: @Claude yes, it is want I look for now I have edited my post, any references?

Comment: @Paul https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qS4H6PEcCCA isn't the one I saw some time ago, but is maybe better in terms of explanation

Comment: I found how to do it in the description, but with mathematica, I am using python, I will try to translate, but it is not easy!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific shape, I would suggest using the Desmos graphing calculator to approximate points on your desired boundary. Follow this link here to see an example of what I mean: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pkdtcwkthr

You can upload the picture you want, then eyeball enough points on the boundary to approximate the shape of a bunny. This will give you a finite collection of complex points, say $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^N$. From here, you want to find a parameterization $$p:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$$ such that for some collection $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^N$, we have $p(t_n) = z_n$.

Here's my attempt at finding an interpolation method, though it is unfinished. I would encourage you to verify that this method works for interpolating $\{z_1,z_2\}$ or $\{z_1,z_2,z_3\}$.

For $\{z_k\}_{k=1}^n \subset\mathbb{C}$, $\{t_k\}_{k=1}^n \subset (0,1)$ given, set $$p(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n z_k l_k(t), \quad l_k(t) 
= \frac{ \exp\left((2\pi i)\omega_n\displaystyle\prod_{j\neq k} (t - t_j)\right) -1}{\exp\left((2\pi i)\omega_n\displaystyle\prod_{j\neq k} (t_k - t_j)\right) -1},$$
where $\omega_n$ is chosen so that $p(0) = p(1)$.

Notice that $l_k(t_k) = 1$ and $l_k(t_j) = 0$ when $j\neq k$. Hence, $p(t_k) = \sum z_k l(t_k) = z_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. It remains to be shown that one can choose some $\omega_n$ to satisfy $p(0) = p(1)$.

Comment: Thx, I have edited my question with respect to your answer. Now the problem is to interpolate correctly in python.

Comment: I have updated my original answer to provide more information on interpolation methods, though an important detail is still missing.

Comment: The expression you propose, gives an interpolation of the curves, but it has no reason to extend to an univalent map. In fact I have just discovered, that this problem is quite hard. The idea is to use the Schwarz-Christoffel formula but you have to compute the prevertex (which play the role of your t_k), it is possible as explained in : https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math401.F09/t.pdf, but it seems highly no trivial, I will try to implement something in the next weeks...